# Looking for a way to export GCP Datastore entity data into csv file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, export-to-csv

I would like to export data from a specific GCP Datastore entity (kind) into a CSV file. I would have thought that the gcloud or gsutil CLIs would be able to handle this but I haven't found a way as yet. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box functionality to export Datastore entities directly in csv format.

A possible workaround you may follow is:

- [Export the specific kind data](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_specific_kinds_or_namespaces) to a Cloud Storage bucket with the following gcloud command

  `gcloud datastore export --kinds="KIND" gs://your_bucket`
- [Import your Datastore](http://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore) export into BigQuery
- [Export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in) the BigQuery table as a csv file

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for that, it works perfectly. The only thing I'll add is that readers of this answer can reference this link to perform the second step in your answer (Import your Datastore export into BigQuery): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore